# Initialize pydantic model with missing parameters

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have the following two pydantic models for a `Users` table in my database for a FastAPI application:

```
from fastapi import Form
from pydantic import BaseModel

class UserCreate(BaseModel):
  username: str = Form(...)
  password: str = Form(...)

class UserInDb(BaseModel):
  id: int
  username:str
  hashed_password: str
```

I use the `UserCreate` class to get form data needed from the client to create a user and then I map it to `UserInDb`. This is how I initially implemented it:

```
password = user_create_instance.password
hashed_password = some_hashing_function(password)
user_in_db = UserInDb(**user_create_instance.dict(), hashed_password=hashed_password)
```

This however throws a `value_error.missing` error because `user_create_instance` does not have an `id` parameter which `UserInDb` expects to be passed in but the value for that comes from the database.

This issue is fixable by doing something like `id: int = None` when defining the attribute in the class but it doesn't feel right to do it this way. Is there a better approach?

Comment: If this is the step where the user is created, why don't you create your user in the database, so that you get your ID, and then create a `UserInDb` from that?

Comment: You know what I read this comment right after I implemented what you just said!